# iPhone SDK: Can I deploy my app store version to my phone for tests?

Tags: iphone, deployment, entitlements

Just to make sure, that I don't miss something: Can I deploy my ready-to-be-uploaded app store signed version to my own phone again in order to make the final test? Currently I can't, catching "Entitlement error 0xE8008016". I'not appearing those problems with the AdHoc version of the app.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You use a different certificate for signing the distribution version. If the only thing you changed in your final and distribution build was the signing identity, the app will run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That seems not to be true. I *can* if I use XCode...
Confused

Comment: you should use the comment function at the answer if you want to add something or discuss it...

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Build and Archive" you get the app added to the organizer. I think from there you can upload the app to the store and you can also create an ad-hoc version from the same binary. (The organizer will re-sign the binary with the correct key)